# How to navigate to Facebook page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I created my own site and my own Facebook page.
I add follow me button on site.
in that user have to follow me either on facebook or on twitter.
Problem: How to navigate user to first login page and then after successfull login to my facebook page

Comment: The concept is redirect url Please you can find out google

Answer (score 0):

Place image and navigate to login page on image click like following:-

```
<asp:Button ID="imgbtnFaceBook" CausesValidation="False" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtnFaceBook_Click"/>

 protected void imgbtnFaceBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Response.Redirect("yourLoginPageLink");
        }
```

On login page check credentials and redirect to facebook page like following:-

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // check login Credentials
           Response.Redirect("yourFaceBookPageLink");
        }
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

Comment: By using above code I can redirect to login page of facebook.But how to navigate to my page?

Comment: @Piya ok I got your question now. You need to learn about single sign on.

Comment: how to add sign in column of fb on my fb page

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:Button ID="imgbtnFaceBook" CausesValidation="False" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtnFaceBook_Click"/>

 protected void imgbtnFaceBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/yourPageLink");
        }
```